# Compare strings in two column from a postgres table using Python

Tags: python, syntax

I have following table in Postgres11.0

```
col1  col2       col3          col4
1     drug       Galactose     Galactose
2     biological Galactose_1   Galactose
3     drug       Galactose     Galactose
```

I am working on a python script which can compare two column values per row (col3 and col4), if they are equal. I am able to connect to the remote host and the database table and can fetch the rows as well. But the comparison operator giving syntax error. I am new to python so I am not able to find the error in my code.

```
q = "select * from %s.table;" % (staging_schema)
cur.execute(q)
print("Selecting rows from test table using cursor.fetchall")
row = cur.fetchall()
countdown = len(row)

for drug in row:
    if drug[2] == drug[3]
        print(countdown, drug[0], drug[1], drug[2], drug[3])
        countdown -= 1
    else
        print('different string')
```

```
The error I am getting is:

if drug[2] == drug[3]
                        ^
SyntaxError: invalid syntax
```

Is there a better way to do it?

Comment: You are missing the colons: `if drug[2] == drug[3]:` same for `else:`. You could the comparison in postgres directly so it is going to faster: `select * from %s.table where col3 = col4` and you do not need to make in Python

Answer (score 0, accepted):

right of the bat I saw this error - > you forgot to add : on the end, it should be like this:

```
if drug[2] == drug[3]:
```

Also on else, it should be like this:

```
else:
```